# export key word unexpected token EcmaScript 6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I can't use the `export` key word in my js file, for example:

```
export var foo = "bar";
```

In the browser, it throws an exception: `"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token export"`.

What is wrong with this?

Comment: There's no browser which supports the new feature: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export#Browser_compatibility

Comment: Oh. I didn't see that. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The `export` statement is not supported by any major browser as of November, 2015.

Here is ES6 compatibility table:

https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/

Comment: What is alternative in this case?

Comment: You can use a transpiler. Typescript, Babel etc are alternatives